# Copy several files listed in a text file to a new folder

Tags: windows

I need to copy several files listed in a text file to a new folder, i'm not a computer wizard, so please be gentle and simplify it :)

(the Files names are like 201609-ABCD.pdf)

I think below would do it, but don't know how to run it.

{
Iterate over the text file:

for /f "delims=" %%L in (foo.txt) do
Copy the files:

copy "%%L" new_folder
Done:

for /f "delims=" %%L in (foo.txt) do copy "%%L" new_folder
}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> - If ***Source Folder***, ***Destination Folder***, and the ***File List*** reside under the same path:

```
FileList:          D:\Files\FileList.txt
SourceFolder:      D:\Files\SourceFolder
DestinationFolder: D:\Files\DestinationFolder
```

And ***FileList*** contains only the name and extension of the files:

```
File1.txt
File2.pdf
File3.docx
File4.jpg
```

Then your script is:

```
@echo off
pushd D:\Files
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type FileList.txt') do xcopy /hrkvy ".\SourceFolder\%%a" ".\DestinationFolder"
popd
pause
```

> - If ***Source Folder***, ***Destination Folder***, and the ***File List*** reside under the same path:

```
FileList:          D:\Files\FileList.txt
SourceFolder:      D:\Files\SourceFolder
DestinationFolder: D:\Files\DestinationFolder
```

And ***FileList*** contains full path to the files:

```
D:\Files\SourceFolder\File1.txt
D:\Files\SourceFolder\File2.jpg
D:\Files\SourceFolder\File3.docx
```

Then your script is:

```
@echo off
pushd D:\Files
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type FileList.txt') do xcopy /hrkvy "%%a" ".\DestinationFolder"
popd
pause
```

> - If ***Destination Folder***, and the ***File List*** reside under the same path and ***SourceFolder*** is variable:

```
FileList:          D:\Files\FileList.txt
SourceFolder:      %SourceFolder%
DestinationFolder: D:\Files\DestinationFolder
```

And ***FileList*** contains only the name and extension of the files:

```
File1.txt
File2.jpg
File3.docx
```

Then your script is:

```
@echo off
pushd D:\Files
set /p SourceFolder=Enter the path of source folder and press 'Enter':
cls
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type FileList.txt') do xcopy /hrkvy "%SourceFolder%\%%a" ".\DestinationFolder"
popd
pause
```

> - If ***Destination Folder***, and the ***File List*** reside under different paths:

```
FileList:          D:\Files\FileList.txt
DestinationFolder: C:\DestinationFolder
```

And ***FileList*** points to files in different locations:

```
D:\Files\File1.txt
C:\WorkFiles\File2.jpg
E:\File3.docx
```

Then your script is:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type "D:\Files\FileList.txt"') do xcopy /hrkvy "%%a" "C:\DestinationFolder"
pause
```

> - If ***Destination Folder***, and the ***File List*** reside under different paths and ***SourceFolder*** is variable:

```
FileList:          D:\Files\FileList.txt
SourceFolder:      %SourceFolder% 
DestinationFolder: C:\DestinationFolder
```

And ***FileList*** contains only the name and extension of the files:

```
File1.txt
File2.jpg
File3.docx
```

Then your script is:

```
@echo off
set /p SourceFolder=Enter the path of source folder and press 'Enter':
cls
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type "D:\Files\FileList.txt"') do xcopy /hrkvy "%SourceFolder%\%%a" "C:\DestinationFolder"
pause
```

**Update:**

To walk recursively in OneDrive subfolders to find sourcefiles:

```
@echo off
pushd D:\Missing Papers
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type MissingPapers.txt"') do (
 for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%b in ('dir /b /s "%OneDrive%" ^| find /i "%%a"') do
  xcopy /hrkvy "%%b" ".\Searched out"
 )
)
pause
```

- Paste it in a `.txt` file and rename it's extension to `.cmd` and run it.
- If you don't have read permission from source directory, or write permission to destination directory, run the script as an administrator.
- Don't forget to replace examples with real file paths.

Comment: This is a great write up but unfortunately it seems like this copy process is single threaded (meaning it copies the files sequentially) so it ends up being super slow. In my scenario, my text file had about 100k lines and letting it run for about 10-12 hours, it only copied 5k files. I ended up writing a custom C# multi threaded application that copies file simultaneously and its way faster. Heres the fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8IvP6w

Comment: For anyone wondering what the `switches` do... `h - Copies hidden and system files.` ... `r - Overwrites read-only files.` ... `k - Copies attributes. Typical xcopy commands reset read-only attributes.` ... `v - Verifies each new file.` ... `y - Overwrites existing files without prompting you.`

Answer (score 3):

Working off @NetwOrchestration's answer, I had greater success using robocopy instead of xcopy. Robocopy seems to be a little more bulletproof and has simple built in functionality to take a file from a source to a destination with just the file name. [See this post for what I mean.](https://serverfault.com/questions/52983/robocopy-transfer-file-and-not-folder)

**This only works when the list of files is just file names, without paths. Robocopy only intakes the file name, looking for it in the folder you supplied as the Source Folder. So the .txt file with the list of files must look something like this:**

```
MyFile1.bin
MyFile2.txt
MyFile4.doc
```

Code for my .bat solution, which allows you to pass the path to the .txt with a list of files, source folder, and destination folder as arguments to it:

```
@ECHO off
SET FileListTxt=%~1
SET SourceFolder=%~2
SET DestinationFolder=%~3

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type "%FileListTxt%"') do robocopy "%SourceFolder%" "%DestinationFolder%" "%%a"

ECHO DONE COPYING FILES IN %FileListTxt% FROM %SourceFolder% TO %DestinationFolder%
```