# Copy several files listed in a text file to a new folder when list file contain different paths

Tags: windows, xcopy, copy

I would like to copy several files (with different paths) in one folder.
I tried this solution explained here [page of example on stackexchange](https://superuser.com/questions/1152729/copy-several-files-listed-in-a-text-file-to-a-new-folder)
but when I run the file (I choosed .bat file) I have "0 file copied" like that:
[screen capture 0 file copied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1flQ.png)

here is some example of my list.txt :

```
T:/audio/enregistrements/2023-03-mars/maroc_2023/msd1/test.txt
T:/audio/enregistrements/2023-03-mars/maroc_2023/msd6/20230324_0454_0627_ailes oiseau et cris oiseau indetermine cala iris sentier maroc_35.1287,-4.3661_MKH8020_AB_230324_014.WAV
T:/audio/enregistrements/2023-03-mars/maroc_2023/msd6/20230324_0627_0801_ailes mesange guepier europe et chien ou loup cala iris sentier maroc_35.1287,-4.3661_MKH8020_AB_230324_015.WAV
T:/audio/enregistrements/2023-03-mars/maroc_2023/msd2/20230323_0551_0724_bruant fou fauvette melanocephale ailes pigeon ramier cala iris Maroc_35.1290,-4.3661_MKH8040_ORTF__Z_F3_230323_009.WAV
T:/audio/enregistrements/2023-03-mars/maroc_2023/msd1/20230401_0745_0918_alouette lulu_ifrane Maroc_33.5174,-5.1753_MKH8020_AB230401_014_best best mais avec vent.WAV
T:/audio/enregistrements/2023-03-mars/maroc_2023/nagra/20230401_0954_alouette lulu ifrane maroc_33.5152,-5.1763_telinga dpa 4060 nagra7_Pichard20230401094912_002_best_best.wav
```

my script.bat is into T:\audio\enregistrements\2023-03-mars\maroc_2023\ folder. It contains that :

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type "T:\audio\enregistrements\2023-03-mars\maroc_2023\list.txt"') do xcopy /hrkvy "%%a" "T:\audio\creation_sonore\projet maroc\complement"
pause
```

I'm sure folder T:\audio\creation_sonore\projet maroc\complement exist.But there is also nothing in "complement" folder..

what could be the problem please ?
Thanks

Comment: Are you married to using a batch file versus a PowerShell script?

Comment: Thanks Brian, I moved to powershell and it works fine (see below)

Answer (score 0):

In fact I asked to chatgpt, it solved my problem. I post here the solution with powershell :

> Here is the PowerShell script to use to copy a list of files to a
> directory:
>
> ```
> Get-Content "path\to\file\list.txt" | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item $_ -Destination "path\to\destination\directory"}
> ```
>
> Make sure to replace "path\to\file\list.txt" with the full path to the
> text file containing the list of files to copy, and
> "path\to\destination\directory" with the full path to the destination
> directory where you want to copy the files.

It works very well :)